# Check for missing font characters in LuaLaTeX

Tags: luatex, fontspec

I have a document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}
Program the μC, please.
\end{document}
```

When I compile with `xelatex` or `lualatex`, there is a missing "μ" character in the output.  This makes sense because the default font doesn't contain that character, but I need to know when it happens.

With `xelatex`, the `log` file contains a warning:

```
Missing character: There is no μ in font [lmroman10-regular]:mapping=tex-text!
```

Cool.  But with `lualatex`, the output is wrong and there's not a single warning or error to be found.  How can I detect missing characters in LuaLaTeX?

It seems that ConTeXt can use `\checkcharactersinfont` or `\enabletrackers[fonts.missing]`, while XeLaTeX controls it with `\tracinglostchars=2`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is an adaptation of the Context code for missing glyphs:
https://gist.github.com/phi-gamma/5812290.

As the character table shipped with *luaotfload* is currently
experimental, it doesn’t contain the necessary metadata.
Thus the code requires the full version of
[`char-def.lua`](http://repo.or.cz/w/context.git/blob/refs/heads/origin:/tex/context/base/char-def.lua)
from a Context distribution (installing the Context packages from TL
should suffice).

**Usage**:
`\startreportmissingglyphs` initializes the tracker.
Its counterpart, `\stopreportmissingglyphs`, disables the glyph
checker.
Example:

```
\startreportmissingglyphs
  ... some text ...
\stopreportmissingglyphs
```

If invoked with the optional argument `[once]`,
`\startreportmissingglyphs` will report each missing character only
once per font.
Example output:

[image: missing font terminal output]

Note that due to the nature of the Luatex callbacks involved, the glyph
checker works on a per-paragraph basis, and
`\stopreportmissingglyphs` will force a paragraph end.

For reference, I include the full example including the definitions of
interface macros from the gist:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode,fontspec}

%% 1) initialize the tracker code (could go to separate file)
\makeatletter
\directlua{dofile "track-missing-glyphs.lua"}
%% 2) Environment start: the optional argument “once”, in square
%%    brackets, requests that the missing glyph message be printed
%%    only once per character and font.
\def\startreportmissingglyphs{%
  \@ifnextchar[\missingglyphs@start@indeed%
               {\missingglyphs@start@indeed[]}%
}
\def\missingglyphs@start@indeed[#1]{%
  \directlua{documentdata.missing_glyphs.enable"\luaescapestring{#1}"}%
}
%% 3) Environment stop: we need to force a \par here to
%%    have the callback apply to the current paragraph.
\def\stopreportmissingglyphs{%
  \endgraf %% paragraph-based callback!
  \directlua{documentdata.missing_glyphs.disable()}%
}
\makeatother
%% Usage examples.
\begin{document}
  %% Latin modern lacks glyphs for the Greek script so we use that for
  %% testing.
  \startreportmissingglyphs
    Program the μC, please.
    %% Works in math mode (different font model) as well.
    $f = ma$
  \stopreportmissingglyphs

  lorem schmipsum

  \startreportmissingglyphs[once]
    %% With the “once” flag, no message is emitted for repetitions of
    %% missing chars.
    Θάλαττα, θάλαττα.
  \stopreportmissingglyphs
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks!  It's very close.  I'm hitting some errors, though: add the text `$f(x)$` and it will crash with `error: track-missing-glyphs.lua:43: attempt to index field '?' (a nil value)`

Comment: @jim-paris please check the updated code.

Comment: Perfect.  A million upvotes if I could.

Comment: @jim-paris I’ve updated the code again: with the bleeding edge [luaotfload](https://github.com/phi-gamma/luaotfload) installing Context is not required anymore.

Comment: If I add "hello, world \mu" to the test, I get: `error: track-missing-glyphs.lua:50: attempt to index local 'tfmdata' (a nil value)`

Comment: @jim-paris Doesn’t happen here. Anyways I’ve updated the gist with an extra check so the issue cannot occur anymore. Can you try it out?

Comment: Same error.  See [https://gist.github.com/jimparis/5919479](https://gist.github.com/jimparis/5919479).  I made 3 changes: fixed the filename in `dofile`, added a `\mu` to the text, and added my output log.

Comment: Ah, now I see. It should be fixed now. Btw. if you want those math Greek characters to be logged correctly you will have to load unicode-math as well.

Comment: Thanks, no errors now.  I'll look into unicode-math to help catch those.

Comment: Tried the code today for the first time and got `track-missing-glyphs.lua:102: attempt to index upvalue 'chardata' (a nil value)
.
\stopreportmissingglyphs ->\endgraf 
                                    \directlua {documentdata.missing_glyphs....

l.32   \stopreportmissingglyphs`. Has LuaTeX perhaps been changed in the meantime in a way that breaks the code?